# EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer not working in Spring Boot 2 for configuring session timeout

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application where I am configuring the container's session timeout in programmatic way using `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`. It was working fine for Spring Boot version `1.5.4.RELEASE`. Following is the code.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container -> {
            container.setSessionTimeout(24, TimeUnit.HOURS);  // session timeout value
        });
}
```

Now I am trying to upgrade the Spring Boot version to `2.0.1.RELEASE`. And the above code is not working. Can anybody help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some search I found the answer. Posting the same, as this can help others: The code need to change ;

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> sessionManagerCustomizer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        return server -> server.addContextCustomizers(context -> context.setSessionTimeout(24 * 60));
}
```